# Understanding how bond prices change

Tags: india, bonds, mutual-funds, bond-funds

I came across following statement regarding Indian debt funds in [ValueResearch ebook](https://www.valueresearchonline.com/downloads/debt-funds-now/):

> The RBI announced retracting ₹2 lakh crore of banking funds through a 14-day reverse-repo operation in January 2021. Effectively, banks were told to take money out of the debt market and park the surplus with the RBI. This sell-off in the debt market resulted in a fall in bond prices and hence a rise in the yields.

I know reverse repo rate is interest paid by RBI to banks. But what does it mean by "retracting ₹2 lakh crore of banking funds through a 14-day reverse-repo operation"? Why does it mean telling banks “to take money out of the debt market and park the surplus with the RBI"?

Answer (score 0):

The RBI VRRR is a variable reverse repo rate scheme.

By increasing VRRR, the RBI can force the banks to sell low yield debt and deposit excess cash with RBI.